# Openshift Kibana proxy

Tags: openshift, kibana

I have a multi-node Openshift cluster (3.9, maybe I will update it to 3.11).
Authentication to Openshift is not managed by Openshift itself, but I have an external provider, Keycloak, where I use ocp_openid_connect. 
Installations of Kibana, ES and Fluentd are ok.

The problem is with Kibana-proxy.

- Can I get rid of it?
- Can I configure it in order to use ocp_openid_connect?

When I try to access Kibana, I am always redirected to Openshift console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `kibana-proxy` is needed for `OpenShift` `OAuth`. If you want to use authentication(OpenID [0])/authorization(OpenShift), then you need not get rid of `kibana-proxy`. I think you should use external authentication via `OpenShift OAuth`.

[0] [OpenID Connect](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/configuring_authentication.html#OpenID)

Comment: Thank you Daein, I found out that I had a configuration error. Now it works, with Keycloak and oauth-proxy.